# Can Spring Security secure the whole site except a few URLs?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I was trying the follow but it doesn't seem to be working.

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/abc/**" access="permitAll"/>
```

I know it is a little odd to allow some even the root is secured but our requirement is to create a 'brand new' application within the current application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-intercept-url):

> **41.1.24 <intercept-url>**
>
> This element is used to define the set of URL patterns that the application is interested in and to configure how they should be handled. It is used to construct the `FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource` used by the `FilterSecurityInterceptor`. It is also responsible for configuring a `ChannelProcessingFilter` if particular URLs need to be accessed by HTTPS, for example. When matching the specified patterns against an incoming request, the matching is done in the order in which the elements are declared. So the most specific patterns should come first and the most general should come last.

Your modified configuration:

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/abc/**" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can ignore some URL patterns. If you are using java config, you put next method in your security config class:

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/url/to/ignore/**");       
    }
```

XML analog:

```
<http pattern="/url/to/ignore/**" security="none"/>
```